# Hiding DocuSign Links in Brand Settings Not Working

Tags: docusignapi, branding

I've set the Brand to hide the Help and About links but they are still showing for some reason.  This is the only Brand I have configured so it is definitely using this one.

As a test I set my own Help Text and URL, which I was immediately able to see, so I cannot figure out why the hiding option isn't actually working.

[image: Links Hidden In Brand Settings]

[image: Links Still Showing]

Comment: How do you use this brand? do you see other elements of this brand showing up?

Comment: It is the only Brand I have set up and it is the default.  I see everything else that has been configured.  To validate that these settings were being saved, I unhid the Help one and entered random Text + URL, and that immediately replaced the default "Help & Support" menu entry.

Comment: Confirmed I see the same, trying to figure out of this is a bug. Will come back to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this feature only works if you have it enabled for your account.

By that I mean, that if you just create a brand and check the boxes to hide these links - the links will still show.

You will need to contact either customer support or your account representative to enable this functionality in your account.

Comment: Is this documented anywhere?